# override a custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

With `ruby on rails`, I have a `player` model that has many `games`. However, the player should have at least three games. I have a custom validator that adds to errors if there is not three games.  I can create a player with three games by declaring in the `player` model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :games
```

and use a nested hash of player and games attributes to create the `player` and its games.

However for testing purposes I sometimes want to add the games one at a time, using `rspec` code like

```
player = create: :player
game = create :game
player.games << game
```

But this will not work because `create :player` triggers the custom validation and so fails because it does not have three games.

Is there any way to do this. If I am unable to do this, I can only test sensitivity to a particular game by crafting a nested hash, which makes it hard to see what the test is doing, as the key change is deep in the hash.

Comment: You can add an attr_accessor to your model as skip_validations and  on your factories pass skip_validations: true, so then you can check in your custom validation and skip the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would **not** suggest skipping your validations, even in your Rspecs unless it can't be avoided. If *possible*, modify your Rspecs to respect the validations instead.

You could do something like this:

```
let(:player) { build(:player) }
let(:game) { create(:game) }
let(:another_game) { create(:game) }
let(:one_more_game) { create(:game) }

it 'test something' do
  player.games += [game]

  # Do your stuff

  player.games += [another_game]

  # Do some more stuff

  player.games += [one_more_game]

  # and now that `player` object is valid, you can do:
  player.save!

  # Check your expectations here
end
```

**Note:**

- Instead of creating a `player` object with no games, i am building the `player` object, which is allowed. You don't need to create something unless you really need it.
- I have modified your variables with the use of [`let`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). They are better suited for Rspecs.

I hope, this solves your problem. If not, please show more of your Rspec code and we can try to modify it to support validations.

Comment: This is useful, particularly the idea of being able to add to the player.games array without invoking any validations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom methods to persist objects

```
factory :player do
  to_create {|instance| instance.save(validate: false) }
end
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-methods-to-persist-objects